# Deleting row leaves empty cell?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running into a problem where i'm trying to delete a row from a Mysql table. This is the code I wrote :

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM members WHERE name='$_POST[delmember]'";
$retval = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$retval) {
    die("Couldn't delete data: " . mysql_error());
}
```

The code to print my database :

```
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM members';
$retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
if(!$retval) {
        die("Couldn't get data: " . mysql_error());
    }
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    if($col == $cols) {
            $col = 0;
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
        echo '<td align="center"><a class="stats" href="members.html?stats='.$row[0].'">' . $row[0] . '</a></td>';
        $col++;
}
```

This actually 'empties' the row, but leaves an empty cell that actually shows when I print my data. I have to then go to phpMyAdmin to delete the empty space manually. I do not understand why it does this.

I am still a beginner and programming is really just a hobby of mine, but I would appreciate if someone would give me clues and point me to the right direction.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What happens if you run `SELECT * FROM members WHERE name='{$_POST['delmember']}'` and get the associative array **after** you've deleted the row?

Comment: **DO NOT** ever inject user variables from `$_POST` into query strings. You **must** escape any and all values using [proper SQL escaping methods](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You're also using the deprecated `mysql_query` interface that's being removed in future versions of PHP. If you want your code to continue to work, you'll need to switch to something supported like [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're just getting started with PHP, [try to follow best practices](http://biasedphp.com/php-commandments).

Comment: I understand there are many things I am doing wrong, and I will look into everything that you gentlemens have suggested to make my code appropriate and clean. However, I'm still having issues with my following code (which currently 'works' and not yet deprecated). Also why do you suggest not using $_POST in my query strings? Is it about SQL injection attacks? If so what do you suggest using?.

Answer (score 1):

To better learn MySQL syntax, fire up a console to a session of MySQL and type some commands directly.  Your syntax *looks* correct, but we don't know the rules of the database you're using or what view you're looking in.

It's hard to tell if you're seeing an artifact of phpMyAdmin, or a consequence of some other aspect of your database, or if it's a consequence of the code you're using to "print" the data.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. For further information, I am only using one field called name. I have no ID attached to anything so I would have assumed that by deleting this name field the whole row would be dropped. I will add the code I am using to print my data on my original post.

Comment: @JonathanLachapelle we still can't see the code you are using to print the data with, `(code to organize and print my array)` is really not helpful.

Comment: @Jake Ball I've just put the whole thing but this is really not the issue here. My array formatting works absolutely great, the problem resides in deleting entries from my database, when I try to do so it does not delete the field, only empties the data and leaves an empty row, which is then displayed by my print.

Comment: @JonathanLachapelle so you are saying that when you use the DELETE statement it simply clears the affected row and doesn't actually delete it?

Comment: @Jake Ball that is exactly my issue, that is what I've tried to explain in my original post. I am sorry if I've wrongly explained the issue before.

Comment: @JonathanLachapelle and you can confirm that you **have to** delete the data using PHPMyAdmin? This is very odd and strange behavior, some I have never seen before. The formatting code will show blank table rows when certain criteria is met, which makes me wonder if that is causing confusion. Try delete the row, then **reload** PHPMyAdmin and confirm the row is still present.

Comment: @JakeBall I confirm that I have to delete the data using PHPMyAdmin. One strange thing i've noticed is that when I am deleting data, it leaves the row blank but does not delete it. When I enter data, it uses the empty row and fills it with data even though I properly use INSERT INTO statement.

Answer (score 1):

try it like this.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM members WHERE name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["delmember"]) . "'";
```

btw, if `name` field is not unique then it is not a good idea deleting users by name, you should use id field as primary key and use id for all operations.

and the other thing is use mysqli or pdo instead of mysql.

[read the warning](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Adding **mysql_real_escape_string** to that variable being accessed makes no difference in this matter.

Comment: i didn't just added escape function, he use post data wrong i corrected it actually.

Comment: Actually @rcpayan what OP did works, even if it does throw a warning.

Comment: The code in the OP works it just isn't the correct way of doing things, the issue with the code is not the fact that he hasn't quoted the post value or the fact he hasn't escaped the data, that was the point I was getting at

Comment: @JakeBall Adding `mysql_real_escape_string` makes an enormous difference if you value your career.

Comment: @tadman I would suggest not even bothering with that and converting database code to either mysqli_ or PDO.

Comment: @JakeBall Absolutely. Any code with `mysql_query` in it either needs to be ripped out and replaced now, or ripped out and replaced when PHP drops support for it in the future.